# How to show the 1st fragment when back button is pressed?

Tags: xamarin.android

I'm new to Mobile Development

I am currently developing a Telephone Directory app from **Xamarin Android**, in this app, I have 4 Fragment(HomeFragment, AboutFragment, DirectoryFragment, and SyncFragment).

HomeFragment is the first fragment that shows from the app. When I click the item **About** in the side bar then pressed the back button, it works well because i used **`AddToBackStack(null)`** before **`commit()`** in the main activity.

But the problem is, let's say I open the app then it shows the **HomeFragment** fist by default, when i navigate to the **AboutFragment**, it shows the **AboutPage**, then if I navigate to the **DirectoryFragment** next and click the back button, i keep on going back to the **AboutPage/AboutFragment**, which is what i want to achieve is, it should go back to the **HomePage/HomeFragment**

In short, what i want to achieve is like the Navigation behavior of the Gmail App.

Anyway this is my code in **Main Activity**

```
switch (e.MenuItem.ItemId)
            {
                case (Resource.Id.nav_home):
                    FragmentTransaction ft = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
                    HomeFragment home = new HomeFragment();
                    ft.Replace(Resource.Id.HomeFrameLayout, home);
                    HideSoftKeyboard();
                    mDrawerLayout.AddDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
                    ft.AddToBackStack(null);
                    ft.Commit();
                    break;

                case (Resource.Id.nav_about):
                    FragmentTransaction ft1 = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
                    AboutFragment about = new AboutFragment();
                    ft1.Replace(Resource.Id.HomeFrameLayout, about);
                    HideSoftKeyboard();
                    ft1.AddToBackStack(null);
                    ft1.Commit();
                    break;

                case (Resource.Id.nav_etel):
                    FragmentTransaction ft2 = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
                    GHQFragment ghq = new DirectoryFragment();
                    ft2.Replace(Resource.Id.HomeFrameLayout, ghq);
                    HideSoftKeyboard();
                    ft2.AddToBackStack(null);
                    ft2.Commit();
                    break;
                case (Resource.Id.nav_refresh):
                    if (CrossConnectivity.Current.IsConnected)
                    {
                        FragmentTransaction ft3 = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
                        SyncFragment sync = new SyncFragment();
                        ft3.Replace(Resource.Id.HomeFrameLayout, sync);
                        HideSoftKeyboard();
                        ft3.AddToBackStack(null);
                        ft3.Commit();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Toast.MakeText(this, "Please connect to the internet to sync records.", ToastLength.Long).Show();
                    }

                    break;
```

Comment: Have you tried the Pop `BackStackInclusive` flag?

Comment: Do you use `DrawerLayout` and `NavigationView` to achieve that? If you use `Replace` method from `FragmentTransaction`, it will remove all of the existed fragments. Do you achieve Back arrow's click event？

Comment: for what is Pop BackStackInclusive? where should i put it base on my code given above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override the `OnKeyDown` method like following code.

```
  public override bool OnKeyDown([GeneratedEnum] Keycode keyCode, KeyEvent e)
    {
        if (keyCode == Keycode.Back)
        {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = this.FragmentManager;
            int count = fragmentManager.BackStackEntryCount;
            for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
            {
                fragmentManager.PopBackStack();
            }
            // your code
            return false;
        }


        return base.OnKeyDown(keyCode, e);
    }
```

I switch three fragment, when I click the back button. it switch to the first fragment.
[image]

**Update**

Do you want to achieve the result that you click back button then back to the desktop when you in the `HomePage`?

[image]

Here is code.

```
public override bool OnKeyDown([GeneratedEnum] Keycode keyCode, KeyEvent e)
    {
        if (keyCode == Keycode.Back)
        {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = this.FragmentManager;
            int count = fragmentManager.BackStackEntryCount;
            if(count>0){
                for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
                {
                    fragmentManager.PopBackStack();
                }
                return false;
            }

        }

        return base.OnKeyDown(keyCode, e);

    }
```

Comment: i've follow your code but it seems i cant close the app now

Comment: @ZippedLips  I update my answer, you can refer to it.